# Mean and St Dev of indexed elements from a separate array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

***The Data:*** I have two numpy arrays. One represents spike or peak amplitudes and the other represents the corresponding peak time stamps in seconds. The zeros represent nothing, and can be changed to NaN if need be. I have copied a small subset of this data below.

***The goal:*** The goal is to find the average and standard deviation of certain elements of my amplitude array based on different windows of time; say, the first 4 minutes (0-240 seconds). In other words, I need to find the indices in my time array that satisfy that condition (0-240), and then apply those indices to the amplitude array in a way that outputs the mean and st dev.

***My attempt:*** Unfortunately, I am relatively new to python and have not been able to find much information concerning manipulation/application of 2D indices. I can say that I have been using very pathetic combinations of numpy.where and numpy.take.

```
t = [[ 111  184  221  344  366    0    0    0    0    0    0]
[ 408  518  972 1165 1186    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [ 208  432 1290 1321    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [ 553  684  713  888 1012 1108 1134    0    0    0    0]
 [ 285  552 1159 1183    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [ 304  812  852    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0]
 [ 192  616  654  724 1143 1290    0    0    0    0    0]]
```

and

```
A = [[ 0.18573314  0.52252139  0.16042311  0.21260801  0.24919374  0.               0.
0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
[ 0.16968141  0.18421777  0.16616463  0.19172084  0.15638406  0.          0.
0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
[ 0.1740181   0.24890002  0.17237853  0.20274514  0.          0.          0.
0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
[ 0.21144188  0.2076988   0.19915351  0.19803788  0.15826589  0.17068694
0.15190413  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
[ 0.15933248  0.17080178  0.15793379  0.15461262  0.          0.          0.
0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
[ 0.19708434  0.1696343   0.26508617  0.          0.          0.          0.
0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
[ 0.2893063   0.16306161  0.1529097   0.15348586  0.24668999  0.18140199
0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]
```

Comment: If the answer below helped you, mark it please as the solution or tell us if there are some issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

# get numpy.arrays in case t and A are not yet numpy.arrays
t = np.array(t)
A = np.array(A)

# find the indices of the timestamps you look for
idx = (t>0) & (t <= 240)

# get the standard deviation and the mean
# A[idx] consists of all those elements in A for which idx is true
np.std(A[idx])
np.mean(A[idx])
```